# Combine methods with identical structure but different parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, coding-efficiency

How would I more efficiently combine these two methods into one?

They have identical structure but different parameters ('key_A', 'key_B') and different storage variables (self.storage_a, self.storage_b)

I could make key_X be an input to a generic method, but it seems tacky to pass in self.storage_X when self is already being passed.

```
def method_a(self):
    some_list = list(irrelevant_extraction_function('key_A', self.some_dict))
    self.storage_a = [item['address'] for item in some_list]

def method_b(self):
    some_list = list(irrelevant_extraction_function('key_B', self.some_dict))
    self.storage_b = [item['address'] for item in some_list]
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj With what condition? Why not factor out the common code into a separate method and then call it from `method_a` and `method_b` passing in `key_X` and assign the result to the appropriate variable.

Comment: @AChampion so I would call: `self.storage_a = self.generic_method('key_A')` and `self.storage_b = self.generic_method('key_B')` This also seems tacky because of the two self on each line.  Is this common practice?

Comment: Yes, that would be one approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be easier to just combine the storage into a dictionary within your own class ...

```
self.storage = {'key_A':[], 'key_B':[]}
```

Then, use one function ...

```
def method(self, key):
    some_list = list(irrelevant_extraction_function(key, self.some_dict))
    self.storage[key] = [item['address'] for item in some_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
def combined_meethod(self, key):
    some_list = list(irrelevant_extraction_function(key, self.some_dict))
    if key == "key_A":
        self.storage_a = [item['address'] for item in some_list]
    elif key == "key_B":
        self.storage_b = [item['address'] for item in some_list]
```

Comment: Both solutions are six lines.  Looking for a more code efficient solution... if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

maybe (non tested)

```
def method(self, key):
    some_list = list(irrelevant_extraction_function(key, self.some_dict))
    setattr(self, 'storage_{}'.format(key.lower()[-1], [item['address'] for item in some_list])
```